# Select statement to select item in table 1 that does not exist in table 2

Tags: sql

I am writing a simple select statement to compare two different tables.

```
table 1  table 2
a         a  
b         b
c         c
H         d
          e
          f
```

I need to select any item in table 1 that does not exist in table 2.

Comment: show complete table 1,table 2 data

Comment: I don't want to see all the data, but I *do* expect to see what you call your columns & how the tables are related.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, one of which is

```
select table1.col from table1 where 
not exists (select col from table2 where table2.col = table1.col)
```

Comment: This is the "canonical" correct answer, but I'd be selecting * from the outermost query (retrieving all details of the row), and would use the primary-key column (which I expect to call `ID`) as the `select` of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery should do it:

```
Select * from table1 
where Id not in 
  (select distinct col from table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table_1.name
FROM table_1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.name = table_2.name
WHERE table_2.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like there is only one column.
Try this.

```
select * from table a -- select all of the things in a
minus
select * from table b -- remove from it the things in b
```